# Android Gallery widget "jitter" / "jumping" / acting weird

Tags: android, android-widget, gallery, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm experiencing a rather weird issue with the `Gallery` widget in one of my applications, and I think it's time I ask someone else about it, as it's been bothering me for a very long time.

I'm using a custom `Adapter` for the `Gallery` widget, and I inflate a custom layout for each item in the `Gallery` in this `Adapter`. You can see the code for the `Adapter` and layouts below. The `Gallery` widget currently doesn't re-use `Views`, so I'm not using any `ViewHolder` tricks, etc.

**The problem**

The problem is that I'm experiencing "jumps" in the `Gallery` widget when it's running on tablet screens, but it's working perfectly on mobile phones. I'm using different layouts for both types of devices and I know they're being used correctly - I've tested that quite thoroughly.

**What I've tried**

- Changing the `Gallery` item layout width / height - no change. But if I set a background color, it appears.
- Tried removing `Gallery` spacing, but that makes the `Gallery` items overlap each other
- Made sure that the `Adapter` is working and the correct layout is being loaded
- Made sure that I'm not changing any `Adapter` settings in the code
- Cleaning the project

**Video examples of the issue**

The two devices are using the exact same application package with the same code base, only difference is the layouts, as seen below.

*NOT WORKING* - On a tablet (Acer Iconia A500 - 10-inch, 1280 x 800, mdpi): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vN2d61_Ojsc

*WORKING* - On a mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus - 4.7 inch, 720 x 1280, xhdpi): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8s-JfwWofo

**Code - Gallery adapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) Main.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return coverFileNames.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_large_img, null);

            ((ImageView) convertView).setImageBitmap(coverFileNames.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

**Code - Main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMainTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="0sp"
        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:text="@string/mainMyMoviesTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumberofMovies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:text="@string/mainNumberofMovies"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
    </TextView>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spacing="20dp"
        android:unselectedAlpha="1.0" >
    </Gallery>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code - Gallery item layout (tablet, `layout-xlarge-land-mdpi`)**

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLargeImg"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:maxHeight="600dp"
    android:maxWidth="374dp"
    android:minHeight="600dp"
    android:minWidth="374dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/noposterxl" />
```

**Code - Gallery item layout (phone, `layout-normal-port-xhdpi`)**

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLargeImg"
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:maxHeight="300dp"
    android:maxWidth="188dp"
    android:src="@drawable/noposterxl" />
```

*PS. The app in question is [Mizuu](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miz.mizuulite) - there's a free version on Market that you can try out to see the problem yourself. It occurs when you swipe the horizontal scroll view and the next image is just about to be shown. The free version is currently tablets only.*

Comment: Did you try connecting tablet to development machine in debug mode? that may give some clues in logcat.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely nothing in Logcat. I've spent hours and hours trying to solve this.

Comment: I'd say that's called a 'snap to' feature not jumping. Haven't read your code yet just looked at the vid's. ...  You don't the min and max declarations in your xml if you explicitly set the size

Comment: No, the "snap to" happens when you release your finger, not when you're scrolling.

Comment: Reading a quote from a google dev, the snap can happen when a size of a view changes. So the snap is happeneing just as a new view comes on the screen and the old one goes out. Why don't you try checking the convertView for null and re-using it?

Comment: The Gallery widget doesn't re-use Views, unfortunately. Got that confirmed from Romain Guy from the Android team.

Comment: I had a feeling it didnt. Have you tried using a dynamically created imageview, instead of from an inflator?

Comment: As in creating the ImageView from code instead? Yeah, tried that - didn't work either. Besides, I need to be able to use different layouts, so the inflator is required and as you can see in the video, it's working on the phone.

Comment: Tough one, hasn't happened to me yet! I posted an answer anyway some1 seems to have a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out that this is **a bug in Android 3.x**, and that it's fixed in Android 4.0 - which explains why it works on the Galaxy Nexus and why it wouldn't work on my Acer Iconia A500 on Honeycomb. I've upgraded to a Transformer Prime and it works flawlessly on that as well.

The problem now is the fact that users on Android 3.x will experience the bug and blame me for it when it's not my fault...

Answer (score 3):

Found this that kind of sounds like your problem:

http://www.unwesen.de/2011/04/17/android-jittery-scrolling-gallery/

The fix is to override these two methods. I'm not too sure it's the right way to go:

```
private long mLastScrollEvent;

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
  long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  if (Math.abs(now - mLastScrollEvent) > 250) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
  }
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
    float distanceY)
{
  mLastScrollEvent = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

It has a hacky fix, suppose you could give it a go.

There is also a bug report filed:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16171

Comment: I'm just wondering why it's not happening on the phone? It's running ICS, while the tablet is on Honeycomb - not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain, but because this jump occurs when getView() is being called I think it has to do with the fact that Gallery doesn't recycle views correctly. However if that is the case I don't know why it would work better on a phone than a tablet, but I suspect that it has to do with either the fact that the phone has a slightly faster processor, or that the images that are being used in the gallery may take up more RAM on the tablet since they are able to be larger on the screen.

If you watch your cat log while you are scrolling on the tablet, does the Garbage Collector run when the pause occurs? If so that is what is causing the pause effect, and I think if it is then it is likely due to the new Object being inflated with each call to getView().

Someone fixed the bug that causes the Gallery not to recycle and released it under the name "EcoGallery" it is somewhat of a hassle to include it in your projects, because you have to manually include a few java files and a few other resources. But if you implement that and test it on the tablet it I think that it may help to alleviate your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Doesn't have anything to do with the processor speed or image size, though. They're basically the same speed and the images are identical in size.

Comment: Maybe it is an ICS fix? I have access to an ICS tablet that I can test it on there on monday. Will insignificant mp4 video files show up in the Gallery if they are just small mp4 files that are video files but aren't like hollywood type movies? I actually tried this afternoon but I don't have movies on any devices and I couldn't seem to get the mp4s that were present on the device to show up.

Comment: You'll need to set up file sources first and there's a setting enabled by default that filters <50 MB files out :-)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually decided to use the `HorizontalListView` by Devsmart instead of the `Gallery` widget. It's not the exact same, and it's lacking a few features compared to the `Gallery` widget, but it's perfectly smooth, capable of re-using `Views` and doesn't "jump" when scrolling through the items. Also, it's not center-aligned like a `Gallery` widget, which is another thing I've wanted for some time.

The HorizontalListView widget is available from here: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

Comment: Another plus one for this scrolling element